# ssrs multiple datasets from a single stored procedure

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I would like to know if there was a trigger which i can use to drop a temporary sql table when a report is closing in ssrs?

### Background

I deserialise data in a stored procedure and after deserialising i want to reuse the data, so the plan is to put the deserialised data in to a temporary table and create multiple stored procedures with different result sets (To be used with multiple datasets in ssrs report) and finally drop the temporary table with deserialised data.

Currently i am thinking may be i should create a sql agent job which will drop the table everyday at a certain time (say 1am in the morning).  However I have a sneaky feeling that there might be a better way to do this?

Any help is greatly appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: Temporary tables (#something) are automatically dropped when connection closes.

Comment: You can use 'view' instead.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, do you mean connection from reporting server to sql?

Comment: yes, connection from reporting server to sql server. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186986(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Ok. That would not be ideal as the temporary table will be created with deserialised data and if the connection to sql is not closed and report is ran again, the deserialised data will be doubled in length.

Answer (score 0):

My assumptions:

1. You can't de-serialise the data when you run the report because it
   takes too long?
2. You are happy for the data to be out of date for your report - because you are thinking of creating a table at 01:00 and potentially running the report at e.g. 17:00

You use the phrase temporary table but that's not what you mean. A temporary table in SQL server is one which is available for the lifetime of the connection and is then dropped.

If my assumptions are correct your plan is fine. You wouldn't drop the table though - Have a look at [TRUNCATE TABLE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms177570.aspx).

You may want to use [SSIS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx), however it's not worth it for really simple procedures.

Comment: Good point about out of date data. You are correct in saying that and as you can imagine it is not ideal.

Yes having to deserialise the data again mean twice the amount of wait to load the report. 

I create temporary tables in my stored procedures and drop them at the end of the stored procedure. Currently this stored procedure is returning a result set which I am using in one of the datasets however i want to modify the results and use it in different dataset. Not sure how?

SSIS is something new so need organisational approval and all that. So have to stick with SSRS unfortunately.